# How to hide a UIButton's imageView?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have a simple function to hide/show a button's image and text:

```
func switchTimingOnOff(duration: Double?) {
    if duration != nil {
        timerButton.imageView?.isHidden = true
        timerButton.setTitle(String(Int(duration!)), for: .normal)
    } else {
        timerButton.imageView?.isHidden = false
        timerButton.setTitle("", for: .normal)
    }
}
```

By Apple's document the `imageView`'s properties are read/write, but I can't hide the image.

I'm trying to avoid setting the button's image to `nil`, so I can restore the image when the function is called a second time, is there any way to simply hide the `imageView`?

Comment: Use this `timerButton.setImage(nil, forState: UIControlState.Normal)`

Comment: @iphonic I want to just hide the image instead of removing it

Comment: This is the way to do it.. You can't hide it directly, when you want to show it set the image back again.

Comment: assign some transparent image. just a transparent rectangle

Comment: @heximal that still removes the original image, doesn't it?

Comment: then store it to some controllers property (image that you're trying to hide and restore)

Comment: this image... is it a part of application bundle?

Comment: @heximal it's the same bundle with the view controller file

Comment: @heximal that's what I'm going to do

Comment: I don't understand the problem. why can't you instantiate this image again?

Comment: You could alternatively just create a custom view containing an `UIImageView`, `UILabel` and a `UIButton` that sits on top of both. Then you can write method for this custom view to show/hide the image view when you need and because the label is separate to the image view, it does not get hidden. As the others have pointed out, you can create a property that holds your `UIImage` for the button then set the button's image to nil, to hide and set button's image to be the stored property to reassign same image back to button.

Comment: @BrightFuture have you figured how to do this?